# accessing variable from within a different sub

Tags: vb.net

I have this,

```
Public Class posData
    Public Property strLabel As String
    Public Property strX As String
    Public Property strY As String
    Public Property blnAvail As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal strLabelID As String, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
        Me.strLabel = strLabelID
        ' Format = "<PinX F='53mm'></PinX>", "<PinY F='204mm'></PinY>"
        Me.strX = "<PinX F='" & X.ToString & "mm'></PinX>"
        Me.strY = "<PinY F='" & Y.ToString & "mm'></PinY>"
        Me.blnAvail = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

Im utilzing this within another sub to build a list called PosList..

```
Public Sub SetUpCoords(ByRef PosList As HashSet(Of posData))
    Dim a1 As New posData("a1", X_coords(0), Y_coords(0))
    Dim a2 As New posData("a2", X_coords(1), Y_coords(0)) 
    Dim a3 As New posData("a3", X_coords(2), Y_coords(0))
```

and so on and so on, however i want to call this method and populate the list in my button click sub so i have added this in my button click event.

```
 Dim MyPosList As New HashSet(Of posData)
 SetUpCoords(MyPosList)
```

then i want to loop through all the objects within my list so i have a for each position in posList, inside this is where the problem occurs, i want to be able to write something like this, a1.blnavail, this is not happening however, i know i can use position.blnavail but i need to hardcode the position for my logic to work correctly, what am i doing wrong?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use another data structure, like a Dictionary, that uses a key? You could then key each item with a1 etc. and access the items in a for loop using the key.

Comment: What is the difference between that structure and the hashset? Would the key be coded as a string?

Comment: A Dictionary is generic type so you can chose the key type and the value type: Dim myDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, posData)

Comment: If position.blnAvail <> False, this is one of my conditions within the loop, instead of position.blnavail i want to say a1.avail? you thin using a dictionary would get round this then

Comment: The dictionary allows you to access items via their key: dim currentPos as posData if myDictionary.TryGetValue("A1", currentPos) then if currentPos.blnAvail then...

Comment: ahh i see i get it!! could this be done for multiple positions for example if mydictionary.trygetvalue("A1",currentPos) and mydictionary.trygetvalue("A2",currentPos) <-- i guess this is where the problem occurs for the hashset as well.. i need to say if a1.blnAvail <> false and a2.blnavail <> false and a3.blnavail <> false then... how can i get round current position so that it will know that i am trying to check all three?

Comment: TryGetValue populates the second parameter with the value if it's found. So you could do: TryGetValue("A1", pos1), TryGetValue("A2", pos2), etc. If pos1.blnAvail <> pos2.blnAvail, etc. There's probably a more elegant solution but this will do it.

Comment: this should work the only thing that untidy is that i have a long list of pos, meaning i would have to declare variables for all wont it?